# Removing characters (digits) after the first dash (-) from the end of a fileName

Tags: command-line, bash, files, sed, mp3

I have thousands of .mp3 files that have recently been required and were appended with a dash `-` and a series of various amounts of numbers. I would like to remove the last dash and the numbers to right of it.

Some examples are:

```
songName-artistName-12345.mp3
songName(1973)-artistName-12345.mp3
songName-artistName12d-12345.mp3
```

What I would like is:

```
songName-artistName.mp3
songName(1973)-artistName.mp3
songName-artistName12d.mp3
```

I have tried this:

```
ls | sed 's/\(.*\)\(-.*\)/mv \"&\" \"\1.mp3\"/' | bash
```

But, I've been getting a

```
syntax error near unexpected token '('
```

I've tried escaping any `/` but that wasn't much help either. I have all these songs in one folder. And another folder with `.wav` files.

Thanks for taking the time and reading!

Comment: Welcome! You should take a look at [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

I think this shoud do it:

```
for f in *.mp3; do
  echo "Moving $f to ${f%-[0-9]*}.mp3"
  # below the action commented
  # mv "$f" "${f%-[0-9]*}.mp3"
done
```

Output:

```
moving songName(1973)-artistName-12345.mp3 to songName(1973)-artistName.mp3
moving songName-artistName-12345.mp3 to songName-artistName.mp3
moving songName-artistName12d-12345.mp3 to songName-artistName12d.mp3
```

Comment: while this is a valid solution, it does not answer the OP's question for why his does not work.

Comment: @JayEye that's right, but I Ieft a comment on why you should not parse the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an Ubuntu-specific question, but anyway:

Recall that the shell still expands metacharacters inside double-quoted strings. In all likelihood, some filenames may contain shell metacharacters, such as `$`, which mess up the output, possibly compounded with some interaction of the locale and how `ls` likes to put filenames with non-alphanumeric characters in quotes (although it should not do that when the output is a pipe). Try using single quotes for your output, and enclosing the sed arguments in double quotes instead. For good measure, reset the locale to something neutral and use `ls -N`:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ ls -N | sed "s/\(.*\)\(-.*\)/mv \'&\' \'\1.mp3\'/" |bash
```

Just in case you have different versions:

```
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.4

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make that middle match non-greedy or it will eat your artist name:

```
$ printf %s\\0 *.mp3 | \
  sed -znr 's|(.*)-[^-].*\.mp3$|mv \"&\" \"\1\.mp3\"|e'
```

However, rename will be much faster:

```
$ printf %s\\0 *.mp3 | \
  rename --null 's/(.*)-.*?\.mp3$/$1\.mp3/'
```